# sed replace line 3 after match with variable

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a file like this:

```
[profile.one]
username=sam
password=secret
email=something

[profile.two]
username=kate
password=secret
email=something

[profile.three]
username=mary
password=secret
email=something
```

I want to create a shell script that changes the password in `[profile.two]`. The new password will be a variable (triggered by another shell script. For example the new password will appear as `$1`.

I know I should use sed, but after that I'm struggling to work out the syntax.

Comment: With GNU sed you could use a range, and over that range do the substitution for the password= using a capture group `sed -E '/^\[profile\.two]$/,/^\[/ s/(password=).*/\1newpass/' file`

Comment: The file looks like an INI-File. Does it always look exactly like this, or can it be a general INI-File, i.e with all syntactic elements allowed for such a file type?

Comment: "I know I should use `sed`" is incorrect.  You believe you should use `sed`, but you are mistaken.  This is almost trivial with `awk`.  Set RS to the empty string and it does almost all of the work for you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Not sure `awk` would help much here, even with `RS=''`. You'll have to substitute something in the second record anyway and this will look about the same as with `sed` (without the simplifications offered by the capture groups, unless it is GNU `awk` and you can use `gensub`). So, you'll basically replace `/^\[profile\.two]$/,/^password=/` with `NR==2` (a bit simpler) but `s/^(password=).*/\1$1/` with `sub(/\npassword=[^\n]*/, "\npassword=$1")` (a bit more complex). Unless there is a trick with `FS` I do not see?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet If you can assume the fields in the records are in the same order, it is almost as simple as `$1 == "[profile.two]" {$3="password=" new_password}1`, and `gsub` is available in most `awk`  See my answer below for details.  But I agree; this is not quite "trivial" and whether it is a significant improvement over the idiomatic `sed` solution is debatable.   They are all fairly fragile.

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation is to search from the start line to the replacement line, then in that range search and replace the replacement line.

```
sed '/^\[profile\.two\]/,/password=/{
    s/password=.*/password='"$1/;}" file
```

Once this works like you hope, you can add the `-i` option to write the change back to the file, instead of to standard output.

This is inherently brittle in that `$1` mustn't contain characters which are significant to `sed` in this context - in particular, newline or slash.

This looks explicitly for `password=` rather than hoping that it will be exactly the third line after the section heading.

Comment: Overall, this is a good solution, but as @EdMorton points out in his excellent comments below, this fails if the new password contains `/` or `&` or any of  several other characters strings (which ones exactly will probably change with the implementation of `sed`, eg `\n` will probably work in some `sed` and fail in others.

Answer (score 1):

sed doesn't understand literal strings and so any sed solution that uses regexp replacement will fail given various values of the password (unless you [sanitize every replacement metacharacter and delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) it could contain or use a solution like [@potong's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77766117/1745001) that reads the password from a "file".

Awk, on the other hand, does understand literal strings, e.g. using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pass="$1" awk '
    /^\[/ { f=($0 == "[profile.two]") }
    f && match($0,/^password=/) { $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ENVIRON["pass"] }
    { print }
' file
```

```
$ ./tst.sh '`~!@#$%^&*()_+-   ={}|[]\:";'\''<>?,./'
[profile.one]
username=sam
password=secret
email=something

[profile.two]
username=kate
password=`~!@#$%^&*()_+-   ={}|[]\:";'<>?,./
email=something

[profile.three]
username=mary
password=secret
email=something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "/\[profile\.two]/{n;n;s/secret/$1/}" fileName
```

Note: [ and . characters need to be escaped to match literal

[image]

[image]

Note: the meaning of the two $1 is not the same. The `$1` within the `changePasswd` function receives the first argument passed to the function; and `$1` for `changePasswd` call receives the first argument passed to the script.

test result:

[image]

Comment: The single quotes prevent the shell from expanding `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Putting code in low-contrast screen shots is dubious at best; probably the passage which explains the two meanings of `$1` should have the code as text instead. (But why do you need a function at all here? That's just an unnecessary complication.)

Comment: @tripleee i am a newer, I've put up a lot of screenshots just to make the process a little clearer. The definition of the function is to fit the scenario of the problem, since  $N is usually found in function calls or function definitions.

Comment: For many purposes, [screen shots are _less_ clear.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) The OP won't be able to copy/paste the code from the image (and with the low fidelity might have a hard time transcribing it). Quite frankly I think this diversion is more likely to confuse than to help as it is currently presented.

Comment: Separately, this hardcodes "secret" as the old secret; perhaps it would be more useful to replace whatever is after `password=`

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the tip about screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is generally better at this sort of thing than `sed`.  eg

```
$ foo() {
    awk '
    $1 == "[profile.two]" {gsub("\npassword=[^\n]*", "\npassword=" new_password)}1
    ' new_password="$1" RS= ORS='\n\n' input; }
$ foo banana
[profile.one]
username=sam
password=secret
email=something

[profile.two]
username=kate
password=banana
email=something

[profile.three]
username=mary
password=secret
email=something
```

Here, I've created the function `foo` for the sole purpose of getting the password into `$1`.  It would be cleaner to use a named variable, and this is just a cheap literary trick to show how to use the command in a script.

`awk` has the nice feature of allowing you to separate records on blank lines, which is done by setting RS to the empty string.  You can select the desired record by an exact match on the first field as above (here, $1 is not the parameter to the function, but is passed literally to `awk` which uses it to select the first field in the record), and then perform the substitution on only that record.

If you know the password is always on the 3rd line of the record (counting the header as a line), you can simplify a bit and just do:

```
awk '$1 == "[profile.two]" {$3="password=" new_password}1
        ' new_password="$1" RS= ORS='\n\n' OFS='\n' input
```

In all of the above, I am assuming your data is in a file named `input`.

Note that neither this nor the `sed` solutions are robust, and it is difficult (and probably not worth the effort) to make them so.  You might try:

```
 p="$1" awk '$1 == "[profile.two]" {$3="password=" ENVIRON["p"]}1
        ' RS= ORS='\n\n' OFS='\n' input;
```

Comment: That should be `new_password="$1"` as it's an awk variable assignment, not a shell variable assignment, so it'd fail otherwise if it contained white space, for example. It'd still fail with ```\```s in the string though as awk interprets escape sequences when passed a variable assignment in the arg list or using `-v` - you need to pass `"$1"` alone and then populate a variable from it in the BEGIN section and then remove it from ARGV for it to be literal (or use `ENVIRON[]`).

Comment: The `sub()` version would fail if `new_password` contained `&`, just like the sed ones that are doing `s/old/new`.

Comment: @EdMorton I never thought about those issues with variable assignment.  Excellent points!   This sort of solution is inherently fragile, and attempting to robustify it seems futile, but I'll move the assignment to the environment.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
v="s}[r3t"
<<<"password=$v" sed -e '/^\[profile\.two\]/,/^$/{/^password=/{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}}' file
```

Set a password in `v`.

Replicate the password as a one line file and feed it into the sed invocation using the here-string.

In the sed invocation, search for a range beginning with `[profile.two]` and ending with an empty line (or the end of the file).

Within the range above, match a line with `password` and replace it by the line provided by the here-document then delete the current line.

N.B. Passwords will and should contain special characters such as `$*&[]` etc, therefore to avoid these messing with sed itself, pass the password as a line from a separate file. In this case a here-string.

Comment: nitpick - `/password/` should be `/^password=/` so it can't match on `username=foopasswordbar`.